# Stuck in the tutorials

Tags: nodeos

I was following along the tutorials till this page.

https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/learn-about-wallets-keys-and-accounts-with-cleos

I am unable to find the ~/eosio-wallet/config.ini file, I do however am able to see the /tmp/eosio/config/config.ini, not sure if this is the same thing.

The tutorial asked me to use the keosd command but did not teach me how to set it up, I was following along and did not skip any part.

[image]

Later the tutorial ask me to cd to eos/build/programs/nodeos. I've used the search function and managed to find only one eos folder, however it does not contain any nodeos or keosd .

[image]

So right now I am just stuck not able to move forward with the tutorial.

Comment: you're skipping many steps if that's the first article you're doing. start [here](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/docker-quickstart) if you want to use docker or look [here](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/getting-the-code) if you want to install everything yourself

Answer (score 1):

I just built 1.05 and after I run nodeos to get its config.ini to generate, I see 2 configs with:

`sudo find / -name config.ini`

```
~/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/config/config.ini
~/eosio-wallet/config.ini
```

Be sure to run nodeos once as the build does not come with a config.ini for nodeos.  It will produce one after you run it.  I'm not sure when the keosd one comes in.

Then you should be able to edit with:

```
sudo nano ~/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/config/config.ini
```

Comment: ok thx for info